# Change input validation type by HTML Selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I'm curious how I might hack together a way to detect what the user has chosen from the selection of options of a form. Depending on their selection will change the way the input field text is process.

**Desired Effect:**

option **A** : accepts text, so its processed right away,

option **B** : accepts emails to be validated before continuing the form processing.

option **C** : accepts emails, so their email validated before continuing the form processing.

In the end a all three options are appended to a text file. So far, I can only get it to validate the emails.

Thanks in advance.

HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" class="subscription-form form-inline" id="subscribe" role="form">
                    
 <h4 class="subscription-success"><i class="icon_check"></i> Thank you for requesting... </h4>
 <h4 class="subscription-error">Something Wrong!</h4>
                    
 <select id="iam" name="usertype" class="form-control input-box">
 <option data-placeholder = "Enter A username" selected value="A">Enter  A account username</option>
 <option data-placeholder = "enter B email" value="B"> Enter B email </option>
 <option data-placeholder = "enter C email" value="C"> Enter C email </option>
 </select>

 <input type="email" name="email" id="subscriber-email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control input-box">
                    
 <button type="submit" name="submit" id="subscribe-button" class="btn btn-default standard-button">Submit</button>
                    
</form>
```

JS - So far only detecting selection and changing placeholder text:

```
$('#iam').on('change', function() {
var placeholder = $(this).find(':selected').data('placeholder');
    $('#subscriber-email').attr('placeholder', placeholder); 
});
```

PHP - So far only validating email and appending results to file:

```
<?php
 // Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
 if ( isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
  
$selected_val = $_POST['usertype'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable

$e_mail = $_POST['email'] . " - is a - " . $selected_val . " ," . "\n";
file_put_contents('email-list.txt', $e_mail, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}
?>
```

Comment: what is the result you want to achieve? I mean in js or in php ?

Comment: what you actually want? that is unclear. Please specify?

Comment: I have edited  my post for a little bit more clarity. @anantkumarsingh

Comment: Are you want when first option is select your input type changes to text-field, and for rest two it will be email type field? isn't it?

Comment: Please tell what i asked?

Comment: @gurlCode: What solution did you come up with in the end or do you still need any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what little novice understanding of JS and PHP I poses, I created 3 input fields - Name/Username/Email. For type A needed a Name and Username combination for submission. For type B & C I needed a Name and Email Combination for submission. So I hide the email field when Type A is selected from options and submitted visible fields. When either Type B or C is selected I hid the Username field and keep the Name and Email fields visible and submitted their contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate it in php all you need to do is setting the option value to the type you want to validate instead of x, y and process it accordingly. If you need those values (x and y) you could set the values to a format like x;email and y;email, split those in php and get the original value plus the validator method.

If you wish to do so in javascript it gets a bit more tricky. This should help to get you started to set the type according to the selected option. The correct names and id are up to you to put.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <Script>
            function createInputField(e){
                var tS = (e || document.getElementById('inputFieldSelector')); //The type list
                var tC = document.getElementById('inputFieldContainer'); //The field container we append our input to

                if (tS && tC){
                    while (tC.firstChild) tC.removeChild(tC.firstChild); //Empty the container

                    var tO = tS.options[tS.selectedIndex]; //Selected option
                    var tE = document.createElement('input'); //The dynamic input field
                    tE.id = 'inputField';
                    tE.type = (tO.getAttribute('data-type') || 'text');
                    tE.placeholder = tO.getAttribute('data-placeholder');
                    tC.appendChild(tE);
                }
            }

            function validateInputField(){
                var tE = document.getElementById('inputField');
                if (tE){
                    if (tE.type == 'number' && (tE.value.trim() === '' || isNaN(tE.value))){
                        alert('This is no number..');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (tE.type == 'email' && tE.value.indexOf('@') === -1){
                        alert('What email is that?');
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true
            }
        </Script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'createInputField()'>
        <form onsubmit = 'return validateInputField()'>
            <select id = 'inputFieldSelector' onchange = 'createInputField(this)'>
                <option data-placeholder = 'Enter Text' data-type = 'text' value = 'Influencer'>Today I want text</option>
                <option data-placeholder = 'Enter EMail' data-type = 'email' value = 'B'>I feel like entering an email</option>
                <option data-placeholder = 'Enter Number' data-type = 'number' value = 'C'>How about a number?</option>
            </select>

            <div id = 'inputFieldContainer'>
                <!--In here we are going to create the input field according to the selection.-->
            </div>

            <button type = 'submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```